# Elastic search attachment ingest pipeline transform to html instead of plain text

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-search-attachment-processor, elastic-search-ingest-pipelines

Is there a way to tell attachment processor to transform file to html instead of plain text. I would like to preserve tables for example. Apache Tika supports that https://tika.apache.org/1.8/examples.html which this processor is based on. I could use it directly for example with a container instance from https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/tika but i might be just missing some options to set this.

Attachment processor documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/attachment.html

It works well with all kinds of files it is just that i get plain text back which i can not use in my app later because of the requirements.

Thank you for any info.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible with the current version of ingest attachment. I don't think there's anything in the making.